# IBM Db2 SQL Alchemy adapter -- issue with client driver

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, db2

I run into this error trying to use IBM Db2 SA adapter, and really am at a loss as to what I should do. Perhaps there's some mismatch between the Db2 client driver and the Python package. Would appreciate any guidance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/d/projects/backend/database_provider/sql_alchemy_connection.py", line 45, in connect
    engine = create_engine(uri, case_sensitive=False)
  File "/Users/d/projects/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 456, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/d/projects/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 87, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/Users/d/projects/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db_sa/ibm_db.py", line 104, in dbapi
    import ibm_db_dbi as module
  File "/Users/d/projects/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db_dbi.py", line 35, in <module>
    import ibm_db
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/d/projects/backend/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
  Referenced from: /Applications/dsdriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /Applications/dsdriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
```

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur 11.3.1, Python 3.6.8, and the following libraries:

```
ibm-db==3.0.1
ibm-db-sa==0.3.5
SQLAlchemy==1.3.8
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/540

Comment: Thank you! yes, that worked. If you'd like to post that comment as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.